# Using std::minmax_element for a user data type

Tags: c++

```
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
public:
  int x, y, z;
  Point(int ix, int iy, int iz) : x(ix), y(iy), z(iz) {}
};

int main() {
  vector <Point> v = { {1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 1, 0} };

  auto min_max = std::minmax_element(begin(v), end(v));
  
  return 0;
}
```

In this program I get an error at the line where ***minmax_element*** is called in MSVS2019.

Also it would be very helpful if anyone can suggest a compare function for ***Point*** data type.

Comment: "an error" what's the error message? Points in 3D space do not have a clearly defined comparison relation that would have a minimum and maximum. [Are you experiencing an XY problem?](https://xyproblem.info/) What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `if anyone can suggest a compare function for Point data type.` Calculate the distance to `Point(0,0,0)` and compare it.

Comment: What about using x-y-z three keywords comparison? like when xyz are the same, return false, xy the same return by z's order, if x the same return y's order, else x's order.

Comment: @dratenik looks like the error (error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found) was due to not having a < operator.
Regarding the comparison, basically I was looking for getting the left-bottom and right-top point of a polygon poins.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement an `operator<` for `Point`. The easiest way is to use [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), which returns a [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) that has its own [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp), eg:

```cpp
class Point
{
public:
  int x, y, z;
  Point(int ix, int iy, int iz) : x(ix), y(iy), z(iz) {}
  bool operator<(const Point &rhs) const { return std::tie(x,y,z) < std::tie(rhs.x,rhs.y,rhs.z); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> In this program I get an error at the line where minmax_element is called in MSVS2019.

You already realized that this is because you haven't provided a way of comparing your `Point`.

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) lists the requirement that the argument must be [*LessThanComparable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LessThanComparable), ie, having a suitable `operator <`.

> it would be very helpful if anyone can suggest a compare function for Point data type.

I can provide a million, because there is no *singular* natural well-defined ordering on ℤ³. You have to decide for yourself what ordering makes sense for you.

- lexical (x, then y, then z) ordering as suggested in the other answer:

  puts the leftmost point first, and then the higher of two points with the same x, and finally the deeper (or whatever you want to call z) of two points with the same x and y

  this is well-defined in the sense that `a < a` is false, and
  `!(a < b || b < a)` always means `a == b`

  but it's not guaranteed to give you the lower-left and upper-right vertices
- magnitude (ie, distance from the origin, or (x*x + y*y + z*z)

  puts points closer to the origin first, but every point on a sphere (centred on the origin) with the same radius compares equal
- lexical with different ordering ... distance from a different point ... etc.

> basically I was looking for getting the left-bottom and right-top point of a polygon

Is the polygon in a flat z-plane? If so, you don't need to look at `z` at all. If not, you need to decide whether you want the left-bottom-front and right-top-back or what.

Let's assume 2D for simplicity - if the lower-left *edge* is `(0,1) - (1,0)`, which of those corners is the left-bottom? Is it more important to be the leftmost, or the lower-most?

Nobody can answer this for you, because it isn't well-defined. You just have to make a decision about how you want your program to behave.